# Can this test-case timing analysis question explanation be improved?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have asked [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/is-this-the-proper-way-of-doing-timing-analysis-of-many-test-cases-in-python-or) about Python. I am not getting any comments/answers on this. I think I might have missed something leading to this.

What can I improve in the question (like details, more test cases etc.) to get proper reviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Placing a bounty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it might help.

Comment: Did that. Hope that helps to get answers.